# Nuget pinning versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm working on a C# project in Visual Studio 2013 where we develop many nuget packages to be consumed in multiple different applications. We have encountered some nuget.org packages where we want to "pin" to an old version, and have that expression of the old version of the package be centralized.

For example, we are not compatible with Unity 4 or NUnit 3, so we want to stick to the prior releases of those packages.

I don't like using "allowedVersions" in packages.config, because

1. it's not centralized (every project will have to have this entered)
2. The GUI in Visual around updating packages at the solution level [ignores project level "allowedVersions"](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/333)

I've played around with expressing the version pinning in a root level nuget package that had a .nuspec with dependency lines like this

```
<dependency id="Unity" version="(,4.0)" />
<dependency id="NUnit" version="(,3.0)" />
```

which seems to block all consumers from advancing to an unsupported version. I like this because it's simple and I can just tell my teammates to make sure every package includes that root level nuget package.

The one things I *don't* like is that every consumer of this root package will get a reference to packages that they don't necessarily use.

For example, my released application will now have a reference to NUnit, despite not using it at all.

Is there a way that I can express version pinning in Nuget *without* getting these unnecessary dependencies?

Comment: Is everyone consuming this going to be within your organization? If so, perhaps you should just have an internal Nuget server with only appropriate packages in.

Comment: The allowedVersions is the recommended approach from a *config* standpoint (https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning#constraining-upgrades-to-allowed-versions).  I've had success (along with others') with the technique that @JonSkeet mentions above (e.g. just a single network share with packages that need to be scoped--don't let it expand out beyond that).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, everybody will be within the organization. I'm trying to avoid the headache of maintaining external packages on our own server. Also, I like the team having access to external repositories to be able to explore packages on their own.